# expo-face-detector is not working on ejected expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using ExpoKit 34.

expo sdk version 34
expo-face-detector version ^6.0.1
expo-camera version ^6.0.0

FaceDetector is not working on my ejected project.
It was working well on Expo client.
But as soon as I eject the project in order to use native modules, it stopped working.

platform: iOS

I hope someone’s help.